# How can I tweak a basic MAME config (mame.ini) so the games display on an LCD screen as if it were a CRT screen in 2022?

Tags: mame

I’m utterly no MAME neophyte. I’ve played around with arcade game emulators since the early 2000s when there were stand-alone emulators for Mac OS 9 that allowed you to play Pac-Man and such.

And over the years I have rolled along with other Mac OS X and macOS versions of MAME. Most recently I had a small MAME collection of maybe a few dozen games up until 2019 or so. It used [SDL MAME](https://sdlmame.lngn.net).

I ditched them when I decided I just didn’t use MAME that much at the time.

But in the last week or so, I decided to do download SDL MAME again to simply play Pac-Man.

Works fine, but the default display is just literal clean graphics. Okay, that’s fine. But in 2019 or so I had download GLSL filters and set GLSL settings in `mame.ini` to get that CRT look on my macOS machine.

Tried to do that with SDL MAME ([`mame0248-x86`](https://sdlmame.lngn.net/2022/09/29/mame-0-248-released/)) in the last few days and it didn’t work. Either a it changed nothing, resulted in a blank screen or other weirdness.

I don’t think it’s worth sharing the GLSL settings I used since it was a lot of “Hail Mary” attempts based on my searches online for advice.

So in 2022, is there any straightforward way to get CRT display functionality to work on macOS? I don’t want to get deep into configs; I just want some basic CRT “flaws” as I play and that’s it.

Answer (score 1):

### The solution I found is to use BGFX settings.

#### Works great and is far simpler to set up for simple/basic needs.

The official MAME docs [explain what BGFX](https://docs.mamedev.org/advanced/bgfx.html) is and how it works. But I found out about BGFX initially via this December 2020 blog post titled “[Setup MAME 0.227 from scratch on Macs](https://mameonmacs.blogspot.com/2017/05/mame-0185-from-scratch-via-mewui-update.html).”

It has good info, but some details — like `mame.ini` line numbers — is a bit out of date. And the overall page is still a bit complex and daunting to read over; and I say that as a programmer and systems administrator with 25+ years of experience.

Sorry, but in my free time goofing around with MAME I don’t want to feel like I am setting up a server for a client!

Anyway, below is the distilled macOS `mame.ini` file I have created based on the advice on that [blog post](https://mameonmacs.blogspot.com/2017/05/mame-0185-from-scratch-via-mewui-update.html). No need to have every single default config setting in the `mame.ini` file. The default values don’t need to be redundantly set in there. The only thing that config should have are custom settings.

So without further blathering, here is the distilled `mame.ini` file that works for me to display games in CRT mode in macOS with little to no hassle:

```
#
# CORE SEARCH PATH OPTIONS
#
inipath                   ini

#
# CORE PERFORMANCE OPTIONS
#
lowlatency                1

#
# OSD VIDEO OPTIONS
#
video                     bgfx

#
# BGFX POST-PROCESSING OPTIONS
#
bgfx_backend              metal
bgfx_screen_chains        crt-geom
```

FWIW, as per that blog post I set `inipath` to simply be `ini` because it is easier for me to manage knowing there is *one* single place where the `name.ini` is loaded than hunt through the various locations that file *might* be set.

Just set this `mame.ini` in the `ini` directory and you are good to go!

But if you just want the pure video settings, these are the three exact items that need to be set:

```
#
# OSD VIDEO OPTIONS
#
video                     bgfx

#
# BGFX POST-PROCESSING OPTIONS
#
bgfx_backend              metal
bgfx_screen_chains        crt-geom
```

Hope this makes the life of some other old-school arcade game fan using macOS easier!